# How client reconnects when one redis node fails

Tags: azure, redis

We are using two different redis clusters on azure):

- One for cache
- Another for redis pub sub

My question is how clustering work in case of on any Master node failure in both the cases.

How client reconnects to new Master node (when original master fails)?

Answer (score 0):

Your client will establish the connection via cluster node, not directly to the master or slave.

Having said that, the cluster will always point to the current master, ie, when your master fails slave will take over as master and the cluster IP will point to the current master's (Old Slave's) IP.

This is a basic functionality of any clustering system.

Comment: Thanks Karthikeyan! I read somewhere that in case sharding is used (along with pub sub), client is connected to one of the shard. And it only listen/send message to that shard. Shard itself communicate with each other. They send all the messages to other shard so that client can listen to all messages. What would happen in this case?

Comment: Here each shard is a clustered environment. So a shard (cluster IP) will communicate to another shard (cluster IP). Ultimately it will directly go to current master.